# Pattern with optional groups

Tags: c#, regex

I have a pattern which has groups. These groups are all optional.

The full posible pattern is:

```
==A=B++C+D#E-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F
```

But can also look like this

```
==A=B++C+D#E-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F
==A.A++C.C+D.D-F
=B++C-F
++C+F-F-F
```

It is not possible to get determiner in the group such as (Group A is no '=' possible).

So i tried these regex:

```
(.*)?\=\=(.*)?\=(.*)?\+\+(.*)?\+(.*)?\#(.*)?\-(.*)
```

Problems:

1. If an group is missing, not match
2. The group with '#' (E) contains the first group '-' (F)

   - 001.002
   - PLC.003
   - M01.001
   - P1
   - test-KF2 --> wrong, should be test
   - KF3 --> wrong, should be KF2-KF3

What is my fault?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on exactly what you are needing but I can see that of your four examples only one of them has three `=` in it and your regex has three non-optional `=` in it so only the first could possibly match.

Comment: Group1 is prefixed by '==' and Group2 is prefixed by '=', both optional... why their non optional?

Comment: You placed the question mark after a group - it means the group itself is optional but the '=' is not.

Comment: @Suplanus: If you use the `?` modifier it effects whatever is before it. In this case that is the bracketed group. The fact that the `=` are outside any of the brackets means they aren't effected by the `?` so they are not optional.

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this by building up each stage, so, your "A" group starts with `==` and cannot contain `=`, so that section could  be matched by `==[^=]+`, but the whole group is optional, so I'd use it as `(==[^=]+)?`, applying the same principal to your "B" group, which starts with a single `=` and cannot contain a `+` would give an optional group of `(=[^+]+)?`, working along the all your groups would finally give something like:

```
(==[^=]+)?(=([^+]+))?(\+\+([^+]+))?(\+([^#]+))?(#([^-]))?(\-(.*))?
```

I've made assumptions as to the characters that are not allowable in any given group, and also assumed every group is optional (so the empty string matches), and no group requires a previous group (so it is valid that D could appear without C) - those assumptions can corrected with additional grouping, or adjusting the character classes, so, for example, the following allows separate F groups (which might be handy if you're parsing data)

```
(==[^=]+)?(=([^+]+))?(\+\+([^+]+))?(\+([^#]+))?(#([^-]))?(\-([^-]))*
```

Comment: Thank. Its still near, but the second pattern gives these back for the first value (i dont need the group value without prefix): 
==A
=B
B
++C
C
+D
D
#E
E
-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F
F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F

Comment: What do you mean by "gives these back for the first value"?

Comment: This is the result of the regex (group values).

Comment: Most regular expression parsers will return the entire string that matched as the first item, and then each group in turn. You've not mentioned which language, or regular expression engine you're using, but I'd suggest checking its documentation